# Abbreviations: StatsModels handling NaN

Tags: regression, python, autocorrelation, statsmodels

In StatsModels there are keywords to specify how to deals with NaNs.

'none' := no checks for missing values

'drop' := drops missing values

'raise' := raises an error

But there is another keyword: 'conservative'. I don't understand what this does.

[Here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf.html) is the documentation, but it is not explained what is does.
I'm especcially interested in what is means in the contect of Autocorrelation.

Comment: I noticed that 'conservative' interploates missing values. Is there any good gocumentation that explains what it does more precisely?

Comment: The statsmodel developer tends to answer questions quickly on https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/pystatsmodels

Also the unit tests might help - https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/34ae057b1726dcf14a395d48c9895adb6b020b7c/statsmodels/tsa/tests/test_stattools.py